# Page Rank Impact On 301 redirecting a directory (folder) to a new domain?

Tags: google, seo, pagerank

I write a lot about programming and Linux, especially because I am relatively new to both of them.

But now, I would like to separate them both - - programming stuff on the same domain (say example.com), but move and 301 redirect Linux stuff (currently at example.com/linux/) to a new domain (say linuxeg.com). As of now, example.com has a pagerank of 4. Will linuxeg.com get a PR of 4?

Precisely, I will be redirecting a directory to a new domain. So, will the new domain carry the pagerank and power of the directory? I am looking forward to a knowledgeable answer for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

301 redirects do carry PageRank over to the new URL but [some of it is lost due to a dampening factor](http://www.marketingpilgrim.com/2010/03/google-confirms-301-redirects-result-in-pagerank-loss.html).

Comment: so, do you think it's going to be okay? (it would be fine if I get at least 3 or 2)

Comment: You'll probably stay a 4 and your rankings may actually improve if you chose a good domain for your new site.